# Leaflet/Leaflet Routing Machine: Is there a method to determine if a Lat and Lang is on the street?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

Using [leaflet-topography](https://github.com/slutske22/leaflet-topography) I can get the elevation and slope data for a given point using Lat and Lang.

I got that data:

```
latlng: LatLng {lat: 40.74224422475555, lng: -73.76170149999999}
topography:
aspect: 279.4623222079068
elevation: 29.600000000000364
resolution: 57.847966427070006
slope: 1.2047623336529816
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

But is there a function out there to say:

> With a given latitude and longitude I'll tell you if its on the street?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OT but my take (palindrome): https://jsfiddle.net/4kc0fodz/

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I really thought what I had was a legitimate question. Guess the gatekeepers didn't think so.

Comment: It wasn't because you didn't ask anything. You presented working code, which is OT for stackoverflow ;)

Comment: That was funny as it wasn't working!

Comment: Ok, that was missing from your question though. Usually you post error messages, output vs. expected output, etc.